# How many crossings are there in an X-ray of a ball of yarn?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, entropy

This is a second question about statistical geometry, starting from the image https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ball_of_yarn_10.jpg that shows a typical ball of yarn. Assume idealized yarn that is unstretchable and infinitely flexible.

If we take an X-ray of an average ball of yarn (ball radius , yarn radius ), how many crossings will we see, on average?

Probably (but I am not sure), the total length will go like $^3/^2$. What can be said about the number of crossings?

Comment: could you define what you mean by a "crossing"?

Comment: Is "statistical geometry" a well known field? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I just haven't heard of it. Is this problem of trying to figure the statistics of crossings in a 3d->2d projection a known problem--a question that has been asked before or studied before?

Comment: @hft Here is another statistical geometry question which I think is better defined: [In a ball with random thread/strings, how does the density of threads/strings change with radius?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468700/in-a-ball-with-random-thread-strings-how-does-the-density-of-threads-strings-ch/468708).

Comment: It's interesting to think about the mathematical meaning of "average ball of yarn". Do you have any idea of how to make that notion well-defined?

Comment: No, I have no idea!

Comment: To Mike Finn: a crossing is when two segments of yarn cross on the X-ray image.

Comment: To Daniel Sank: the hardest parts seems to be that a ball of yarn requires friction to remain stable (though this might be wrong). And friction is hard to idealize.

Comment: Would the tag for *string theory* be appropriate for this question??